# express-resource mapping elements relationship

Tags: node.js, express

How can I create a server to manage my entity relationships using node.js and express-resources

I meam, if I have a User entity, I can access it `using /user/<user-id>`. But how can I define some properties, using this site as example, `/user/<user-id>/question/<question-id>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var users = app.resource("users", require("./resources/users"),
    questions = app.resource("questions", require("./resources/questions");

users.add(questions);
```